# How to get EKSource for iCloud?

Tags: iphone, ios, calendar, icloud

Trying to implement iCloud Calendar synchronization for iOS.

Need to get corresponding EKSource object to be able to create calendar there. While iterating over the stores the type for iCloud store is EKSourceTypeCalDAV but the same type can be used for other stores as well.

So how can I specify if corresponding store is really for iCloud?

Right now using description text but it's not a right solution:

```
for (EKSource *source in store.sources) {
    if (source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeCalDAV) {
        if([source.title isEqualToString:@"iCloud"]) {
            caldavSource = source;
            break;
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way that how i create calendar on iCloud

```
EKSource* localSource=nil;

for (EKSource* source in self.eventStore.sources)
{
    if(source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeCalDAV && [source.title isEqualToString:@"iCloud"])
    {
        localSource = source;
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: I see but actually source.title can be edited by user from iPhone->Settings->iCloud->Accounts->Description. So right after editing that string you'll be unable to create a calendar or get corresponding source. So the question was how to make it more generic and not that much user dependant.